# HttpWebRequest thorw an error 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am calling 3rd party api from my application, it's working fine in development environment, but when i host it on server with SSL certification it's throw an error 403 forbidden.
when in local host application with ssl it's do the same, in nut shell that api doesn;t work if we install certification in our application.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ccc.xxxx.com/_c/std/api/test.aspx?clientID=545444&pwd=ccccccxxxxxx&QueryID=757575&QueryType=X&version=1");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
request.Accept = "application/xml";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

am i missing some thing or any suggestion related to this.

thank you

Comment: It doesn't matter that code issuing an HTTP request to the outside runs on a site that uses HTTPS. That's definitely a red herring. What's more likely is that your web server has a tied down outgoing firewall or proxy, and that you must authenticate against your proxy or firewall to make outgoing requests. Start by actually reading the response's body and seeing whether it indicates who is giving the 403 and why.

Comment: @CodeCaster i tried this same request from browser and it's works fine on server. in local i debug code but i didn't retify that this is from server firewall issue or remote server.

Comment: Sure, but when you RDP into the server, you're logged in. When running in IIS, the code runs as another user who may or may not have the appropriate permissions in the firewall or proxy.

Comment: ok got it thank you for guide line